# Oracle: invalid identifier on altered session

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, oracle11g

This question is related to the one I asked yesterday ([Oracle: Read-only access to the schema for another user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706260/)).

Basically, what I am trying to do is to give a  user read-only access to a schema so I can test my `java` application being sure I do not write anything to the database unintentionally.

The logon trigger works as far as changing the current schema. However, there is a query I would like to succeed:

```
select backup_time.update_time(?) from dual
```

The package actually makes an update on a table `backups`. I am getting this error:

```
ORA-00904 Invalid identifier
```

The query is executed with `Hibernate`  in  ```java``.

Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to grant permission to `types` as well.